# Qiskit: The parameters of the circuits constructed by QAOAAnsatz will change after decomposition and transpilation

Tags: qiskit, qaoa

When I submit a parametrized circuit as an input for the mixed operator in `QAOAAnsatz`, some strange results appear.

For example, when I submit a parametrized circuit with a parameter `b` as the input for the mixed operator, and set `reps=4`, the parameters of the circuit are `ParameterView([ParameterVectorElement(β[0]), ParameterVectorElement(β[1]), ParameterVectorElement(β[2]), ParameterVectorElement(β[3]), ParameterVectorElement(γ[0]), ParameterVectorElement(γ[1]), ParameterVectorElement(γ[2]), ParameterVectorElement(γ[3])])`

which is correct because parameter $\beta$ will substitute parameter `b` in `QAOAAnsatz`.

But if I transpile this circuit or decompose this circuit, the parameters change to `ParameterView([Parameter(b), ParameterVectorElement(β[0]), ParameterVectorElement(β[1]), ParameterVectorElement(β[2]), ParameterVectorElement(β[3]), ParameterVectorElement(γ[0]), ParameterVectorElement(γ[1]), ParameterVectorElement(γ[2]), ParameterVectorElement(γ[3])])`.

[image: The change of the parameters]

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Hello! This seems very Qiskit-specific, could you open an issue at https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues? That's a more suitable platform to discuss potential bugs like this as you're reaching the developers directly. If you open the issue there could you make sure to include a full snippet, including circuit construction, that reproduces the error? :)